# how does indexing work in a for loop when appending a list?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, append

I´m trying write a function that returns a list with the positions for each capital letter it doesn’t work with when the capital letter in the string is repeated.

```
def capital_indexes(word):
    cap = []
    for i in word:
        if i == i.upper():
            cap.append(word.index(i))
    return cap
```

```
print(capital_indexes("HelloWorld"))

[0, 5]
```

```
print(capital_indexes("HoHoHoHo"))

[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: If you want the indexes then use `enumerate`. And if you use a list comprehension, then the full function body will boil down to one line of code: `return [i for i, c in enumerate(word) if c == c.upper()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work as you expect because the `index`method returns **the first** occurrence of the searched element (some [docs here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/index)).

So... Let's say your code finds the third `H` (for instance) in the string Ho**H**oHoHo. Then, the `index` method asks *"Hey, give me the first `H`"* Which happens on position 0 (**H**oHoHoHo).

I suggest you `print` what you are iterating over. I say this because the fact that you're calling your item `i` (*usually* used for indices) makes me think that maaaaaybe (just maaaaaybe) there's a tiny confusion between the index and the element?.

Maybe just renaming your control variable will help a bit:

```py
def capital_indexes(word):
    cap = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter == letter.upper():
            cap.append(word.index(letter))
    return cap
```

With that in mind, you can now take a look to [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which will give you both the item and the position it's in:

```py
def capital_indexes(word):
    cap = []
    for idx, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == letter.upper():
            cap.append(idx)
    return cap
```

If you want to stick to indices, you have to retrieve the contents of position `idx` in the string:

```py
def capital_indexes(word):
    cap = []
    for idx in range(len(word)):
        letter = word[idx]
        if letter == letter.upper():
            cap.append(idx)
    return cap
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that index method is returning the first occurrence of character.

Maybe you should control the index of letter by an another var like this:

```
def capital_indexes(word):
    cap = []
    index = 0
    for i in word:
        if i == i.upper():
            cap.append(index)
        index=index+1
    return cap
```